# inserting data select into with loop in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am just want to enter forms detail column  data into a database column from a detail block and that must check first entered data which it already have in that column when i entered data data saves in other tables but in `token_staus` is not entering data and message me No data found  for that i write a loop which is not working for me i am making some kind of mistake obviously but not sure where it is

```
DECLARE 
TOKEN_NO NUMBER;
TOKEN_STATUS1 NUMBER;
--TOKEN_STATUS2 := :TOKEN_STATUS;
BEGIN
SELECT SR_NO, TOKEN_STATUS INTO TOKEN_NO, TOKEN_STATUS1 FROM LOOPT2 WHERE SR_NO = :TOKEN_NO;
--IF :TOKEN_STATUS IS NULL
--THEN
LOOP
GO_BLOCK('TOKEN_REC2');
FIRST_RECORD; 
INSERT INTO LOOPT2(TOKEN_STATUS) VALUES(:TOKEN_STATUS);
NEXT_RECORD;
EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';

END LOOP;  
--END IF;
EXCEPTION
  when others then
  message (sqlerrm);
END;
```

Please help me 
Little Foot please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, it would be something like this (check comments within the code): key thing here seems to be a `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block within the `LOOP`.

```
DECLARE 
  TOKEN_NO NUMBER;
  TOKEN_STATUS1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  GO_BLOCK('TOKEN_REC2');
  FIRST_RECORD; 

  LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT SR_NO, TOKEN_STATUS 
        INTO TOKEN_NO, TOKEN_STATUS1 
        FROM LOOPT2 
        WHERE SR_NO = :TOKEN_NO;

      -- if such a :TOKEN_NO exists, that SELECT will return some values
      -- which means that you want to skip it, so - don't do anything
    EXCEPTION
      -- if such a :TOKEN_NO does not exist, SELECT will return
      -- NO_DATA_FOUND which means that you want to perform insert
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO LOOPT2 (TOKEN_STATUS) 
          VALUES (:TOKEN_STATUS);
      WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        NULL;
    END;

    EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';
    NEXT_RECORD;
  END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: bundle of thanks but this throw me error frm-40735 ora-01422 of exception I just want to set token_status column from table as from detailed block where it is also :token_status column for all agt token_No from here is just going in table is token_status in loopt2 column where token_no is already have so Token_status just compare To Token_No and put Token status from :Token_Status in table

Comment: ORA-01442 means TOO_MANY_ROWS, which means that there already are some duplicates for the same TOKEN_NO in that table. If that's OK with you, then handle it (such as my example shows - see the 2nd WHEN exception). If it is not, first remove duplicates from the table.